# Angular Clear Cache On update

Tags: angular, angular2-services, browser-cache

I'm Using Angular 4 in my project. I need help in clearing client browser. Whenever I update my code and deploy the user only seeing the old code until they hard reload ( Shift + R) the page. As a developer it is okay but I don't want to tell my user every time to clear cache on new update. So Is there any way to clear cache by myself once it is deployed so that the users only get the latest updated code without any hard reload stuffs.

Comment: Are you trying to describe *"cache busting"*? Usually you include a hash in the asset path, so when the `index.html` reloads it's accessing a different file. Angular CLI does this by default, if you're using something else (what?) you may have to enable it explicitly somewhere.